# Does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Does this converge or diverge?$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}$$

At the moment, I have: If $n > 0$ it's converging to $1$, and if $n < 0$ it's converging to $-1$.

I'm not sure I'm following it correctly, though.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ is usually understood as $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$. However $\lim_{n\to -\infty} \frac{n-1}{n}$ is $+1$ as well. Where do you see something converging to $-1$?

Comment: I think you're making a mistake with negatives. Even if you substitute $-\infty $ into the limit, the negatives will cancel out, and as @MartinR said, the limit will still approach +1.

Comment: Sorry, yes I didn't mean to put -1. I see both positive and negative values of n would converge to 1 then? So, bar the -1 mistake, I was on the right track?

Comment: Just as an aside: It is more appropriate to ask whether a _sequence_ converges/diverges instead of asking whether a _limit_ converges/diverges. So one would ask "Does $(a_n)_n$ converge?" or "Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist?". (Where $a_n = (n - 1)/n$.)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still learning as I go so thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n}$$
to $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{n}$$

This can be evaluated as $$1 - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 1 - 0 = 1$$

Note that this is same for both $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\rightarrow -\infty$.

The answer is yes, the limit does converge.